# How to make a call to multiple rest service in mulesoft

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-component

I have a requirement where i need to call multiple rest service.

currently I am invoking only one rest service, as the file is huge we have splitted into parts (like 1 to 10k , 10k to 20k, 20k to 30k...so on)

the flow is designed to read the complete file and now it has been splitted.

Flow goes like this:

HTTP requester(WS call)----businesslogic.

I want to invoke multiple services(1 to 10k , 10k to 20k, 20k to 30k...so on )and use the same common business logic flow.

how to configure?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to call rest api's in sequence for every record the you can do that inside batch steps.

If you need to make rest api call's with out any sequence then you can use scatter gather inside batch.

Number of records to be processed in parallel can be set by configuring batch size.

References: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/scatter-gather
https://dzone.com/articles/part-1-mule-batch-processing-introduction

Comment: thanx for the help

Comment: thanx for the help...........the below URL's need to be call one after other how to configure in Mule?

Currently I am using HTTP requester where i am able to call first URL by passing URI and query param.

My question is how to call another 2 URL one after other?

i have defined in property file as:

workday.contextpath.getURL1 = Z+-+ISU/Z_-_All_Domains_-_All_Domains
workday.contextpath.getURL2 = Z+-+ISU/Z_-_INT93-_All_Domains
workday.contextpath.getURL3 = Z+-+ISU/Z_-_RPT_D_

Comment: you can do in batch step

Answer (score 0):

Mule allows this by using the `scatter-gather` component. Be aware of exception handling in this use case. In case one or more routes fails, you need to control this.

```
<scatter-gather timeout="6000">
    <!-- custom-aggregation-strategy class="implement and place your class here if you need a custom strategy"/-->    
    <http:request config-ref="requestConfig1" path="/path1" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="requestConfig2" path="/path2" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <http:request config-ref="requestConfig3" path="/path3" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</scatter-gather>
```